# Mapping web pages in Apache server

Tags: apache, web-applications, mapping, localhost, localserver

I am developing a web application and i am using apache server to deploy it!
I want stop going to particular web page directly when i type in the url on my local server as that page should always appear after a successful Log-in.
What is the approach that i've to consider?

Comment: You can use session for managing restriction on pages.

Comment: I have used session for user login and log out and i also have disabled back button after logging-out.But this i am not able to do.

Comment: check session is set or not in that page

Comment: No, i've just started a session in that page,It goes like this.<?php

session_start();

?>  Rest is html and <script> type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!i found an answer.Can you please let me know whether that serves my purpose?I think it does! http://www.astahost.com/topic/14857-simple-user-validation-script/

Comment: in that script cookie is used. but if you want to restrict direct access to that page(from url) session is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per reference to comment i am writing code.

in login page if login successfully.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['uname']="XYZ";
?>
```

below Page that open after successfully login.

```
<?php
  session_start();
   if(!isset($_SESSION['uname']))
       //redirect to login page here 

?>
```

here if the session variable not set that it transferred to login page again. means page can't access without login.